# How to find a secluded cabin to rent

Tags: hiking, wilderness

How can I find a nice, secluded cabin to rent, somewhere in the U.S. wilderness? This almost seems like a word of mouth kind of endeavor, asking friends and friends of friends if they own or know of such cabins but I'm hoping there's a way to search online, for places that I would never hear about otherwise. That's what I'd like to find out from this community.

Some places I've looked:

- [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org) occasionally references cabins.
- [Vacation Rentals by Owners](http://vrbo.com) (VRBO) is has a good interface to narrow down by characteristic.
- Some trail clubs have cabin listings. For example the [Potomac Area Trail Club](http://www.patc.net/PublicView/Cabins/PublicView/Custom/PATC_Cabins/Cabins.aspx).
- Many State web sites, like [Virginia's State Parks site](http://www.dcr.virginia.gov/state_parks/cabgen.shtml), list their cabins.
- Searching [TripAdvisor](http://tripadvisor.com) and [FlipKey](http://flipkey.com) for cabin helps too, though I haven't found secluded wilderness cabins there yet.

Each of these is helpful in their own right.

Are there other options? The more searchable (like VRBO and TripAdvisor) the better. The more secluded options listed (walk-in rather than drive-in, for example) the better. The more the resource describes the surrounding trails and scenery the better.

Comment: I'm thinking the folks at the [Travel Answers SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/?as=1) might possibly be better able to answer this question. As it stands it's ambiguous enough to _maybe_ fit here, but certainly leans towards 'travel' over 'great outdoors'. That's my two cents anyway.

Comment: But please do not [cross-post](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13805/2509)! I was just suggesting, you might want to ask on [both](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com) [metas](http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com) to find where it fits better, then possibly migrate!